# Получение id пользователя vk

Tags: php, javascript, вконтакте

Добрый день, у меня такой вопрос, можно ли получить id пользователя зашедшего в группу вк, себе на сайт в переменную php? Я слышал человек заходит в группу вк, щелкает там всякие товары и потом через 15 минут ему приходит сообщение о том, что он просматривал такие-то товары, и предлагает ему купить еще что-то. Хотя он ни куда не переходил и ни чего не покупал.
Подскажите возможно ли такое?

Comment: за такое банят, по правилам контакта не разрешено такое делать(спамить в личку купи то купи это), а вообще поидее надо делать бота для группы и то помоему там нельзя отловить клики пользователя

Comment: А как определить для начала, что пользователь зашел в группу?

Comment: написать бота для группы